# Required Fields with unlimited field collection items

Tags: entities

I have a D7 instance with a field collection called field_professions and associated to a content type with "unlimited" amounts of fields. Within this field collection I have two fields that are required (field_professional_user and field_professions). I also have an unrequired field called field_serving_since. For the sake of testing I made the entire field collection required.

Now, when I have an item entered, I can enter a 2nd, 3rd etc. item, but whether I fill out all 3 fields, 1 of the required fields, or the unrequired and none of the required fields, it never validates that the fields are required. I can obviously see the red asterisk, but there is no validation.

Comment: Just came across this and for anyone else concerned, Field Collection now handles this correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced This bug in field collection module ( really I didn't find out why they do this :(  ). There is no way to achieve this ( have unlimited and required fields in field collection ).
You just achieve it trickly . (set it unlimited and none-required) . use jquery for validate( checking filled )  fields.

This problem almost accures when you don't want set default value for field .(if you set default by any edit add a waist item  ).

Comment: I was afraid I'd have to do that. It was my plan B. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @CoryFischer Your welcome